# Please help with dynamic autosave button that only halfway works?

Tags: dynamic, scoping, button, user-interface, autosave

Ive been working on this from morning to midnight (primarily studying the docs that never seem to have useful examples) only to to make very little ground. I am trying to code a dynamic button that performs a recurring `NotebookSave[]` after a countdown `timer[s]` completes and then automatically begins cycle again.

The button should do the following...

1. when inactive label should display `AutoSave`.
2. click replaces label with time remaining for next save.
3. when countdown `timer[s]` completes this should trigger `NotebookSave[]`.
4. label should now read `SAVED` for `10 sec` (I think `Pause[10]` would work).
5. automatically start cycle over perhaps by recursive function (only closing notebook will stop autosave).
6. and finally the entire thing nicely packaged in a `DynamicModule[]` which I should find doing a *piece of cake.*

From the code below you can see I only completed steps 1 and 2 (step 3 attempted but failed). Any help for steps 3 - 5 would be most appreciated. I also include a small sampling of my many bad attempts so you would take pity on my wretched soul.

```
timer[s_ : 600] := Dynamic[s - Clock[{0, s, 1}, s, 1]];
s = 10;
Button[Dynamic[x, {(x := #) &, NotebookSave[]}, 
  Initialization :> (x := "AutoSave")], x := timer[s]]

(* may ignore these bad attempts *)
(*
Button[Dynamic[x,{}Initialization:>(x:="AutoSave")],(x:=timer[];\
NotebookSave)];
Button[Dynamic[x,Initialization:>(x:="AutoSave")],Dynamic[x,{x:=timer[\
],NotebookSave[]}]];
Button[Dynamic[x,Initialization:>(x:="AutoSave")],x:=Dynamic[t,{t:=\
timer[s],If[t==0,NotebookSave[]]}]]
Button[Dynamic[x,Initialization:>(x:="AutoSave")],x:=Dynamic[t,{t:=\
timer[s],If[t==0,NotebookSave[]]}]]
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Button` will not work for what you want to do, since it will require to set the Method -> "Queued" and then you cannot do anything in the notebook anymore.

I would use `ScheduledTask` and write the information when to save in the "WindowStatusArea". The below code should serve as a proof of concept.
Just execute in inside your notebook and then you can go on using the notebook for other tasks.

```
    With[{nb=EvaluationNotebook[], p1:=Pause[1]},
   CurrentValue[nb,"WindowStatusArea"]="preparing repetitive autosave";
    SessionSubmit[
      ScheduledTask[ 
        Module[{sCountDown = 3,s},
          s = sCountDown
          ; Do[
              CurrentValue[nb,"WindowStatusArea"]=("Autosaving Notebook in " <> ToString[s] <> " seconds")
              ; If[s > 0
                  ,
                    s = s - 1
                  , 
                    CurrentValue[nb,"WindowStatusArea"]="Saving Notebook now"
                  ; p1; NotebookSave[nb]; p1; s = sCountDown
                  ; CurrentValue[nb, "WindowStatusArea"] = "SAVED"]
                  ; p1
                  , {10^5}
           ]
        ]
     , {Quantity[5,"Seconds"], 10^7 }]]
];
```

[image]

Comment: wow i really didn't expect anyone to be so generous as to rewrite a whole application for me. thank so much for all your effort. it will not go to waste.

Comment: the dynamic button would have been included in a `DockedCell` toolbar where all `Buttons` are set to `Method -> "Queued"`. Could `Dynamic` options such as `SynchronousUpdating` have averted notebook freeze?

Comment: I don't think so. What you can do is to start and stop the scheduled task by Button, maybe.
BTW: There is also a standard [NotebookAutoSave](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookAutoSave.html) notebook option, but it is too limited, I think.

Comment: if you dont mind i really like this but works too good (saves every 3 - 5 seconds).. how to stop this unnamed `ScheduleTask`? i removed cell containing code and close/reopen notebook now `WindowStatusArea` has frozen message `Saving Notebook now`. ideally i wish to anchor your solution to a function for starting it. `autoSave[s,p]` would have two arguments: `s` for duration of save recurrence and another argument `p` for length of pause for status messages. and finally how to stop `autoSave[s,p]` . i am about a year in with Mathematica and have no idea how to manage `ScheduledTask`s.

Comment: to test stopping `SheduleTask` i first prepended code with `task=` on new notebook document. then tried `TaskRemove[Tasks[]]` and `TaskRemove[task]`. neither worked. i really like this solution but i cant use it until i figure out how to stop it. i think i can figure out the other things.